# User.Groups has no groups even though they are loaded

Tags: 2013, csom, groups, user

Hi now that we have upgraded (or in the process) of upgrading to SharePoint 2013 I though I'd try and take advantage of some of the new features that it has to offer in the CSOM API.

One is that User now has groups.

[User.Groups property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.user.groups.aspx)

So I thought I would try and use it using.

```
var u = this.Web.GetUserById(this.CurrentUser.Id.Value);
this.Load(u);
this.Load(u.Groups,includes => includes.Include(x => x));
this.ExecuteQuery();
```

`u` has the user and the group collection seems to populate but has 0 groups in it. The user is in a few groups can browse the site - so what gives?

Edit
The code in it's rawest form is

```
var u = this.Web.EnsureUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            this.Load(u);
            this.Load(u.Groups);
            this.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
context.Load(web.CurrentUser);
context.Load(web.CurrentUser.Groups);
context.ExecuteQuery();
//at this point all groups are loaded
```

I've just tried it with SharePoint online and it worked. `context` variable in my example is the [ClientContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext.aspx) object.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. In my case this is an extension of the clientcontext  the currentuser in my case is a user I've made up. But I brought it back to brass then the code would be var u = this.Web.EnsureUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            this.Load(u);
            this.Load(u.Groups);
            this.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: Given that it works for you there, then I wondering if it's a permission/settings thing. The user that the clientcontext is running under is  a site admin so perhaps a setting somewhere...

Comment: Hi there right just still semi looking into this, I've got a workaround from my 2010 days but never hurts to try and find better ways. Anyway I wanted to ask, the groups are these groups the user is directly in? or can they also include groups that they are in because they are in the ad group?